# Open my apps accessibility settings Page android

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, accessibility

I want to open my apps accessibility settings on a press of a button [Desired Page to Open(myApp)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nUuH.jpg)

Was only able to open accessibility settings [accessibility Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGqAB.jpg)

Tried adding data to Intent but got this error
"No Activity found to handle Intent
{act-android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS dat=package:com.testapp4 fig=0x10000000 )"

Code:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
 Uri uri=Uri.fromParts("package",getReactApplicationContext().getPackageName(),null);
 intent.setData(uri);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getReactApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```